# Jersey: Accepting integers for Enum request parameters

Tags: java, jersey

I have some Jersey servlet with the following method:

```
@GET
@Path("/setState")
public String setState(@QueryParam("objId") int objId, @QueryParam("state") ObjectState state) {

     /// bla bla bla ...
}
```

Where the enum `ObjectState` is defined as:

```
public enum ObjectState {
    VISIBLE,
    HIDDEN,
    SELECTED,
    SHADOWED
}
```

Currently, for the clients to call the method, they have to mention the state as a string, e.g. `&state=HIDDEN`.

I want to enable the clients to pass the ordinal enum value, instead of a string containing its name. For example `&state=2` will mean that the value is `SELECTED`.

Currently, I do it manually, by making the following, not very elegant, workaround, by changing the parameter type to an integer and then finding the enum value manually:

```
public String setState(@QueryParam("objId") int objId, @QueryParam("state") int state) {
    ObjectState stateAsEnumVal = stateAsEnumVal.values()[state];
    // bla bla bla ...
}
```

Is there an option to do it automatically and elegantly?

Comment: I think I've seen a question saying that this happened automatically and the OP wanted to disable that behavior. Have you tried keeping your code as is, and passing 2 instead of SELECTED?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it returns error code 404, as it did not find a method to call with such parameters

Comment: @dabadaba - How can I do that?

Comment: @JBNizet - What you say is correct about Jackson, but probably Jersey changes that setting. You can see here that `FAIL_ON_NUMBERS_FOR_ENUMS` is by default `False`: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features

Answer (score 3):

With `@QueryParam` and other `@XxxParam`, non-primitive (and non-list of those primitives) types are allowed to be used, if they follow one of the four rules:

1. The class has a constructor that accepts a string.
2. The class has a static `valueOf(String)` method that returns the type.
3. The class has a static `fromString(String)` method that returns the type.
4. There is a `ParamConverter/ParamConverterProvider` that can handle the type.

The reason the enum works out of the box is because all enums come included with a static `valueOf` method that returns the type. But this is of no use as it expects the string value of the enum as an argument.

What we can do though is add a static `fromString(String)` method. Jersey is smart enough to know that if there is a `fromString(String)` method in the enum, that that method should be attempted to be called instead of the `valueOf` method.

So you can do something like

```
public enum ObjectState {
    VISIBLE,
    HIDDEN,
    SELECTED,
    SHADOWED;

    public static ObjectState fromString(String param) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(param);
        return ObjectState.values()[value];
    }
}
```

This should work. The only problem with this though is that you lose the ability for the client to send the string value.

---

#### UPDATE

Or maybe to support both String and number you could do something like

```
public static ObjectState fromString(String param) {

    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(param);
        return ObjectState.values()[value];
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return valueOf(param)
    }
}
```

Here if the integer parsing fails, you can try to use the default `valueOf`.